# 2nd derivative of function with 3 parametric variables?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, parametric, chain-rule

For the function $f(x,y,z)$, where $x,y,z$ are all functions of $t$, what is the 2nd derivative of $f$ with respect to $t$?

I know that the 1st derivative is 
$\frac {df}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} x'(t)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} y'(t)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} z'(t) $, But can't get my head around the how the chain rule would work for the 2nd derivative.

Comment: Apply the exact same formula and the regular chain rule. Note that it is quite complicated because we now have three multivariate functions.

Comment: Applying the chain rule to the first term of the derivative, I get $\frac {\partial f}{\partial x}\frac {d^2 x}{dt^2} + \frac {\partial ^2 f}{\partial x^2}\frac {dx}{dt} $ How do I apply the partial chain rule to each of these parts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} f(x(t),y(t),z(t)) 
    &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}t} \text{.}  \\
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}t^2} f(x(t),y(t),z(t)) 
    &= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}t} \right)  \\
    &= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} \right) + \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}\right) + \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}t} \right)  \text{.}  \\
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} \right) 
    &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \left( \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} \right) + \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \right) \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}  \\
    &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\mathrm{d}^2x}{\mathrm{d}t^2} + \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \right) \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}  \text{.}  \\
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \right) 
    &=
\left( \frac{\partial \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}{\partial x} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} + \frac{\partial \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}{\partial y} \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} + \frac{\partial \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}}{\partial z} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}t} \right)  \\
    &= \left( \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} + \frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial x \partial z} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}t} \right)  \text{, so}  \\
\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} \right) 
    &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\mathrm{d}^2 x}{\mathrm{d}t^2} + \left( \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} + \frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial x \partial z} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}t} \right) \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}  \text{, so}  \\
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2}{\mathrm{d}t^2} f(x(t),y(t),z(t)) 
    &= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\mathrm{d}^2 x}{\mathrm{d}t^2} + \left( \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} + \frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial x \partial z} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}t} \right) \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}
+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\mathrm{d}^2 y}{\mathrm{d}t^2} + \left( \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} + \frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial y \partial z} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}t} \right) \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}
+ \frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \frac{\mathrm{d}^2 z}{\mathrm{d}t^2} + \left( \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial z} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial z} \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} + \frac{\partial^2 f }{\partial z^2} \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}t} \right) \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}t}  \text{.}
\end{align*}

Comment: I can't believe that you put the effort :')

Comment: Thank you so much this has been a huge help!